# preallocation of memory in matlab / octave

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

I preallocate memory for a large array but the new data appends at the end of the array instead of over writing the data how can I fix this.  So I can preallocate memory for a large array.

note the array is 44101x5001 I just used smaller numbers in the example.

Example:

```
clear all
xfreq=zeros(10,10); %allocate memory

for ww=1:1:10
     xfreq_new = xfreq(:,1)+1+ww;
     xfreq=[xfreq xfreq_new]; %would like this to over write and append the new data where the preallocated memory of zeros are instead of appending to the end of it.
end
```

If you run this you'll notice that it appends the ones instead of over writing the zeros.

Aloha
Rick

Hopefully this explains things better
Allocated array

1)Allocated memory of zeros

```
[0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0]
```

2) Overwriting allocated memory of zeros with a number, the number could be anything not just the number one, I used the number one as an example

```
[1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0]
```

3) Still Overwriting of allocated memory zeros with a number, the number could be anything not just the number one, I used the number one as an example

```
[1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0]
```

the problem is with this line
 xfreq=[xfreq xfreq_new]; %would like this to over write and append the new data where the preallocated memory of zeros are instead of appending to the end of it.
    end

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Which part of the preallocated array are you planning to overwrite?

Comment: @C.R. the xfreq with all the zeros will be overwritten with the new values of xfreq_new from the for loop

Comment: `xfreq(:,1) = xfreq(:,1)+1+ww`?
It´s impossible to tell what are you trying to do. What do you allocate 501 columns and then iterate always for the first column and for 1,...,10?

Comment: You wrote a loop which does not use the iterator `ww` and there seems to be no input data. I don't get what your code should do.

Comment: @Daniel R I'll update it with some more text

Comment: @Fkaria it was an example I'll update it

Comment: Your usage of "over write and append" is nonsensical. The two are mutually exclusive. To "overwrite" is to replace existing values. To "append" is to add new values by extending the matrix in some dimension. If you don't want to append, then don't use `xfreq=[xfreq xfreq_new]`. As @FKaria suggests in the comment, you should just replace the values of the original matrix, `xfreq`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work if you want all your entries equal to `x`

```
  x = (some number)
  A = zeros(10,n)
  for i=1:n
    A(:,i) = x;
  end
```

If you want your columns equal to some other column you have to do

```
  A = zeros(10,n)
  for i=1:n
    A(:,i) = v;
  end
```

where v is a vector of size (10,1)